# Intel graphics cause shutdown on laptop (CPU Intel i7 6700HQ)

Tags: 15.10, laptop, shutdown, intel-graphics, 16.04

when I switch to Intel integrated graphics the laptop fans go on full max and can't be turned off, and then after a few mins the log out window pops up on its own and the computer shuts down, also doesn't matter which drivers being used it always shuts down on its own after a few mins, but works fine when using Nvidia GPU any help would be appreciated.

Should also note that this problem happens on ubuntu 15.10 and Ubuntu 16.04 beta, using different DE's like Xfce or Mate still results in the same problem.

Also upgraded the kernel to 4.5 made no difference, also installed a manual updated driver from Nvidia made no difference.

The problem is it just drains the battery running the GPU all the time when its not not needed, am not bothered if it doesn't switch GPU's automatically like with Nvidia Optimus

CPU- i7 6700HQ, GPU- GTX 960M (2 GB VRAM)

Comment: Please include the details of your processor, integrated graphics, and discrete graphics.

Comment: CPU- Intel i7 6700HQ, GPU- GTX 960M (2GB VRAM)

Answer (score 0):

Previous post got deleted for not being a "proper answer"... -_-.  Oh well.

There is no answer right now. Linux Kernel 4.4 is bugged with Skylake and 4.2 does not support it. 4.3 is a similar but more stable situation, but the iGPU situation is the same.  Bumblebee is also broken it appears on 15.10 for me. Kernel 4.5 is just around the corner and your best bet is trying to install Arch with 4.5 when they update it in the next few days. Apparently Skylake support is much better.

FIXED!
OK... add the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa to your sources with sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers-ppa/ppa, sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get install nvidia-358.  Then go to nvidia-settings and enable the intel GPU.  Logout, Ctrl Alt F1 at the login page, sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-358 (seems unnecessary to install nvidia twice I know, but precautions).  Then sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf and change the line KernelDriver = nvidia-current to nvidia-358 and then Ctrl X, y, Enter.  sudo reboot and you're good to go.

Comment: Yeah your right about bumblebee, installed that then had to enter it in recovery mode to uninstall because it messed things up, afraid the answer would be try another distro so will Ubuntu update to 4.5 one day to? Thanks for your help